# Multiple calls to ajax script not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I am very new (literally less than a few days) to all things ajax, but it is required for a form I am building for my employer.

Basically, no matter what I do it just will not work for more than one function. To elaborate, I am trying to update 4 different parts of a page based on one drop down using `onchange`. Now updating one part works fine, updating any more than that fails... but not only fails, it also fails if for example I do call to ajax part, then just a simple alert... but if I do it with the alert first it works, then falls over again if I put anything after the ajax call. I hope that makes sense. It also works if I do, for example `onchange`, and `onblur` on the same element, it will execute twice. I'll post the code then hopefully it will make more sense.

```
<select name="pType" id="ptype" onchange="dostuff()">
```

So that's the input element...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dostuff(){
ajaxpage('adminincludes/popoptions.php?pID=<?= $sql['pID']; ?>&pType=' + ptype.value,'options');
alert('test');
}
</script>
```

...and that's the `dostuff` code, or an example anyway, ignore the PHP part as it fails regardless of that, that part works fine.

Now the rest of the code is within an external file and I believe that somewhere in there is where the problem lies... however I am new to ajax, and am not the greatest with js as I have never really had a major need for it so just learned what I needed, when I needed.

```
var bustcachevar = 1 //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
var loadedobjects = ""
var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname
var bustcacheparameter = ""

function ajaxpage(url, containerid) {
    var page_request = false
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
    page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // if IE
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    } else
    return false
    page_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        loadpage(page_request, containerid)
    }
    if (bustcachevar) //if bust caching of external page
    bustcacheparameter = (url.indexOf("?") != -1) ? "&" + new Date().getTime() : "?" + new Date().getTime()
    page_request.open('GET', url + bustcacheparameter, true)
    page_request.send(null)
    page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid) {
    if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1)) document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = page_request.responseText
}

function loadobjs() {
    if (!document.getElementById) return
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var file = arguments[i]
        var fileref = ""
        if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file) == -1) { //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
            if (file.indexOf(".js") != -1) { //If object is a js file
                fileref = document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
            } else if (file.indexOf(".css") != -1) { //If object is a css file
                fileref = document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
            }
        }
        if (fileref != "") {
            document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
            loadedobjects += file + " " //Remember this object as being already added to page
        }
    }
}
```

Now like I said, the code works perfectly when only calling `ajaxpage()` once, or multiple times via different events, it just will not work multiple times from one event, even when putting the multiple instances into the `dostuff()` function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is really starting to aggravate me.

UPDATE: This isn't as urgent now as i have done a "workaround" which uses multiple events such as mouseover, mouseout etc on an update link instead. which means it works as i need it to, however it is not elegant by any means and I am still intrigued why it won't work when called multiple times within 1 event?!

Comment: I don't want to throw you off, but you should really really consider using jQuery. it is literally easier to learn the entire library and then implement this than to implement this in plain javascript.

Comment: I have used jquery a few times for different things but I always find that at some point it interferes with something else and my employer is very big on compatibility so I tend to steer clear...not to mention its very slow. But I thank you for your suggestion. Like i said, this works, just not within the same event for some reason, thats the only issue, everything else works perfectly.

Comment: In my experience, one of the major selling points of jQuery is compatibility. It evens out most of the many discrepancies that exist between different browsers and versions. These differenes are just a pain to figure out by yourself for every browser type you need to support. What kind of performance problems are you seeing with it?

Comment: Agreed, jQuery is the way to go.

Comment: Appreciate the input, but using a complete library for one issue still won't give me a solution. I've already found a workaround but would still like to know the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice on lines 26 and 27 of your sample you're repeating:

```
    page_request.send(null)
```

Worth eliminating that before you continue. Could we see a live link to this anywhere so we can perhaps examine generated source?

Comment: Didn't notice that, thats actually not my code, that part is from dynamicdrive.com. Unfortunately not it's a private project for my employer. Do you need the full generated source or the part that the ajax is loading? it's nothing complicated, its just some php outputting different fields. Basically the project is a very custom ecommerce website, this particular part is when a user is adding a new product to the site, they select what type of product it is from a drop down, it then populates 4 other parts of the form, 2 checkbox sections, and 2 text field sections.

Comment: in individual events they can be called no problem, it's only when they are called from within 1 event, no matter what the event type. The problem must lie within the last part of the code I posted. Just can't figure out where, or why. Basically i would think it would load one part, then return to the beggining of the function and do the following ones, but it's like it goes through the function then just can't go onto the next for some reason. I tried adding returns in numerous places within the code to try and force it to exit out or at least give me an error to no avail.

Comment: No problem, can you instead post a full example of your combined call to the ajax function (retrieving all four parts), I'd like to see how they're called in turn.

Comment: It's as posted, they are within the do stuff function. I just shortened it with the alert for testing... It doesn't get to the alert part of the function it does the call to the ajax part then seemingly stops. It doesn't matter what function or call you put in, it will never go past the first function. The information can build a simple test version if that helps and post the code so you can see yourself if I'm not being clear with my explanations.

Comment: Presumably you're putting many calls to ajaxpage in the doStuff() method, but as you say its failing after the first. Yes, please work up a test and post for us to see.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Thanks for the help ill build a version of it tomorrow morning. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No need for me to build a test script the problem was actually with the duplicated line you pointed out, knew it was something in there. Good eye. Thank you for the help.